# Populating $attributes with values from the previous model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I've got a Laravel project (actually a Laravel Nova project) that involves entering a lot of data. To save some time I'd like to pre-fill some of the fields in my form, based on the logged in user's last entry.

I can pre-fill fields via the $attributes variable on my model, called `Product`, like so:

```php
protected $attributes = [
  'category' => 'ABC'
];
```

And I can do this for more dynamic data in the constructor like so:

```php
function __construct() {
  $this->attributes['category'] = Str::random();
  parent::__construct();
}
```

But I'm not quite sure how I'd go about this when I want to retrieve what the user entered last time. For example, I'd like to do this:

```php
function __construct() {
  $user = auth()->user()->id;
  $last = Product::where('created_by', $user)->latest()->first();
  $this->attributes['category'] = $last['category'] ?? null;
}
```

However that ends up in an infinite loop. Same if I call `$this->where('created_by' ...`

Is there a way I can set `$attributes` of a new `Product` based on the last `Product` created by the user?

Comment: You should not be doing this in your model's constructor at all. If you need to populate forms, you pull the data in the controller and pass it to the view for display. A model should not be created until that form is submitted.

Comment: And when you do that, products and users should have a relation in Laravel if they are related in the database. You should not be doing `Product::where('created_by', auth()->user()->id)->latest()->first();` to manually search for a specific user ID, but rather `auth()->user()->products()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();`

Comment: @miken32 I figured that was the case, as I've never had to do it until I started this Nova project.  I'll re-read the documentation for Nova, but I'm not sure if I can access the controller prior to Nova rendering the form.

Comment: Have no experience with Nova, but I'd be very surprised if you didn't have the ability to change the controller's behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the [Nova Defaultable](https://novapackages.com/packages/inspheric/nova-defaultable) package.

Once you add the necessary traits, you can just add `->defaultLast()` to a resource field and it'll default to the last set value. This also works for relationships which is perfect for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Nova fields have `resolveUsing` method, so in your case if you want to populate Text field:

```php
Text::make('Category')->resolveUsing(function () {
    return optional(auth()->user()->products()->latest()->first())->category;
})
```

Comment: This is a start, however it doesn't work for BelongsTo fields (and I assume other relationship fields). If I set `$attributes['product_id'] = 1` in my model, it defaults to the product that has an ID of 1. But if I return `1` in the `resolveUsing` function, it defaults to nothing selected. Also resolveUsing is for modifying data AFTER retrieval from the database, but BEFORE it goes to the front-end. It's not meant for setting defaults, because if I leave `category` intentionally blank, it'll just pre-fill with whatever was set previously.